# kafka multi node set up active-Active

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kafka and have some basic doubts. 
I was trying to do a multinode kafka set up (Active-Active). here is the scenario :-

1. running single zookeeper (port: 2181)
2. started three kafka brokers (9092,9093,9094)
3. create a single topic test (partition: 1, replication 3)
4. started producer using broker list (9092,9093)
5. started consumer on 9092,9093,9094, but all of them are using same topic.

Now my doubts are, when I am sending a message from producer it is consumed by all three consumer,

q1. does that mean it is duplicating the message ?

q2. as producer is running on 9092,9093 then why consumer on port 9094 is consuming the message ? is it because it is using same topic name ?

q3. how I can make sure when i am sending a message from producer it should be consumed by a single consumer ? (I tried grouping but if any consumer is in different group it is receiving the message.)

q4. if I want to distribute the messages between consumers, how I can achieve this ?

q5. any other way to set up a multi node kafka (Active-Active) with single producer and multiple consumers ?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Your consumers must be in different groups. If you don't want the messages to be read multiple times, set group.id

Comment: 2. Ports are server ports. You are running 3 separate brokers that talk to each other. Which one you bootstrap to doesn't matter, you'll be routed to the one you need in both producing in consuming.

Comment: 3. You must use consumer groups for this.

Comment: 4. Not sure what this means. I think you are again referring to not duplicating between consumers, which means leveraging consumer groups.

Comment: 5. It looks like you are in the right track, you just need to read more about consumer groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered in comments, but this is really a question coming down to a lack of understanding about consumer groups in Kafka. This is too long to discuss in this format, so I'll direct you here https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer

Comment: one doubt, we are running our consumer using 5 threads/each (2 different system), but during testing messages are only consumed by one server not on the server (we have 10 partition for the kafka queue). When we are changing the thread number to 2 (single consumer  each server) it's working fine. can you please tell me why it not able to send messages on the other server while using 5 consumer/each server ?